# When viewing questions in tag marked as "interesting", they shouldn't be all marked interesting

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags, design

When viewing questions in one of tags I consider interesting, using URL like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag>`, and I have `<tag>` among "Interesting tags", **all questions** are marked using "interesting tag" style... which result in strange looking page. In my opinion when viewing questions tagged with given tag, this tag should be temporarily removed (for the purpose of displaying given view) from "interesting" / "ignored" tags list.

Having *all* questions with yellow background looks silly.

The idea of *highlighting* is, I think, to be able to distinguish a few questions (those with "interesting" tags) among other questions (those without).  Note that before today (19-07-2009) the behavior was different; perhaps there simply wasn't any syntax highlighting in 'view by tag' aka 'questions/tagged' view...

---

***Edited 21-07-2009***
The **revised** idea is to support highlighting "interesting" / "ignored" tags also in `tagged/` view, but exclude currently viewed tag from the list of tags that highlight. This way one would be able to see *other* interesting tags (or other ignored tags) in `tagged/` view for some interesting tag.

Comment: With the revision does the "by design" tag still apply? I know I'm interested in this view that why I clicked on it.

Comment: I was just about to post a double about this. Whew! I sure like that "related questions" feature. I hope this idea gets implemented; it's kind of redundant to see all the results highlighted.

Comment: Related Link (and closure): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a new behavior that was requested in another item. Prior to this, the "/tagged" page was unique in that it was about the only list of questions where the interesting/ignored filter was NOT in place.

I guess this proves my theorem that:

> for every user who requests a behavior, there exists another user who will request that behavior be removed once implemented

Comment: That can be frustrating, but it is possible to satisfy both groups by including an option in the user preferences. As an example, the Reddit homepage has undergone several changes, but users have a checkbox in their prefs to turn it back to the way it was.

Comment: Ugh. I don't mind site-specific prefs for big behavioral things, but UI colors? Sounds like a job for Greasemonkey...

Comment: Actually the request is not to remove feature, but to fine-tune / enhance it; see my proposal for interesting/ignored filter on the "/tagged" page to not take into account the tag we are viewing. Or would it be too complicated to implement?

Comment: It is mildly ugly to have every question highlighted, but it's seriously bad usability to dim every item when I click on an ignored tag. I clicked on it for a reason, for crying out loud. What reason is there to dim every single item on a page?

Comment: @Jeff, You actually implemented the idea that was edited in, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593) so this could actually be changed to [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 2):

I disagree. Seeing all the answers in yellow when I clicked on a tag I was interested in was the moment I finally understood why some of the items were in yellow some of the time.

If we make things more complicated, it'll be harder for users to discover how the site works. I believe that here being consistant is more important that being pretty.

Answer (score 1):

On the flip side, though; it is at least consistent, and it makes the rules simple. And if they are all going to be the same colour*, does it matter whether it is a block of white or a block of off-white?

(*=give or take the edge case where some questions have another flag that you have marked to ignore)

Comment: Actually, it might be useful when browsing one of your interesting tags to have questions highlighted that trigger another one of your interesting tags. Sort of a double-interesting view.