# Background color for questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching

I have the C# tag as an interest of mine.  It seems like in the last few days, questions with that day are not showing as orange.  If the have another one of my interested tags (like .NET) then they do show as orange.  I tried removing and adding the tag, but that didn't work either.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I'm viewing it. So, this is something that changed recently?

Comment: Yes, it was changed on December 17th. I've converted my comment into an answer since you've confirmed that this is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're viewing questions by tag and that tag is already in your interesting tags, they won't be highlighted unless they also match at least one other interesting tag.

So if C# is an interesting tag and you're viewing all questions tagged C#, they'll only be highlighted if they also match another interesting tag (.net)

You can see the details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593).