# Filter unanswered questions so I see those with tags I frequent

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

Basically the `Unanswered` list should by default contain the questions I can most likely answer: areas/tags I've already asked questions about, searched or marked as favorites.

Perhaps some kind of personalized ranking could be established there. When I land at the page from Google to solve some bug, why not entice me to increase my rep with an ad-like listing of questions that I could answer on the side (rather than just list related questions)?

I'm not that much of an altruist, there always seems to be something I've got to get done. I never just search specifically for questions I can answer to pass the winter. But, if I happened to see a question when visiting the site I could answer, maybe because I just had the same issue a week ago, I'm more likely to take the time to.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking, but maybe try to understand the current implementation as described in [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) and in [Why is stack overflow suddenly orange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593), and then describe what you'd like differently?