# What is the list of interesting questions on stack overflow?

Tags: support, interesting-page

Pressing the [main](https://stackoverflow.com/) button (between the `chat` and `about`) at the top of the page, takes you to the list of interesting questions.

So, how are these interesting questions different from other type of questions? If I click on the `Questions` tab, I get newest, active, etc questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It lists questions that are tagged with your favorite tags or tags you're active in more than other questions. To that end, favorite tags used to be called interesting tags, hence the tab name "interesting".

Note that it also lists more unanswered questions too, see [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes) for the nitty gritty.

Comment: Not really. Favorite questions are still yellow, and ignored are not shown.

Comment: @VJo: There's a higher frequency of uninteresting questions (questions without your favorite tags) in the active tab.

Comment: And in case on is not logged in, [some other magic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593) applies.