# Where are new questions displayed?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I am not a new member for Stack Overflow, but i'm new to Meta. I want to know where are the new questions located on the site ?

Are they in here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions
```

or here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

And what is the difference between these above two locations?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86857/what-is-the-list-of-interesting-questions-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At www.stackoverflow.com is a list of the questions that the algorithm has deemed 'interesting':

[image: main]

At /questions, the newest questions reside:

[image]

The tabs at the top of each page also allow you to change the sort order - 'featured' is the questions with bounties, for example. These tabs actually **remember** the last selected tab, and automatically select it.

Comment: almost; this is the default sort, I think. You can change them both, if you wish, too.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yep - I just wanted to proved the simplest possible solution - Neither the OP nor I am a power user like you mods...

Comment: @Undo just worth to mention that the site "remembers" the last selected tab as it's causing confusion to new users.

Comment: @Sha Huh. I was one of those users. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, now you're not! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The home page has the most recent activity on all questions (asked, answered, etc.)

The `questions` page can be sorted by most recently asked (newest) as well as active, unanswered, etc.

To answer your question:  click on the Questions tab, and sort by Newest.