# What happened to the interesting questions?

Tags: support, tag-watching

About two weeks ago every site I visited (and I frequent a few) had a bunch of questions highlighted in blue.

I remember noticing this on Judaism, skeptics and onstartups.

Is the algorithm now broken, was there a push to do this by mods and it fell off a cliff or was it just something I clicked on?

There are two similar questions on the meta of Judaism and onstartups like this: [Why are some questions highlighted in blue?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/why-are-some-questions-highlighted-in-blue)

pre-post-UPDATE: I just went on Judaism to find this question and notice that there are plenty of blue questions on their homepage, but definitely none on Skeptics or Onstartups.

I can also confirm there are no tags in my prefs.

Comment: No tags in your prefs on Judaism, Skeptics, OnStartups, or no tags in any of them?

Comment: @John - I have no favourite or ignored tags on any site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@xiaohouzi79 linked to a question asking the same thing on the judaism.se meta which contains an answer that explains it, so I'll just quote it here (see the emphasis):

> This is highlighting questions with tags that are in your favorite tags.  ***If you haven't manually added any favorite tags, the system will detect when you have a certain level of activity in a tag and infer one for you.  If you manually add a favorite tag, the system will not infer a tag for you.***
>
> You can customize your favorite (and ignored tags) in your profile on the prefs tab.  You can also customize these settings in the right sidebar of the homepage and the /questions listing.
>
> So, if you would prefer not to have any questions highlighted, you can simply add a nonsense "tag" to your favorites.  Perhaps [unicorns-eating-waffles](/questions/tagged/unicorns-eating-waffles)? (:
>
> <sup><sub>[Why are some questions highlighted in blue?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/why-are-some-questions-highlighted-in-blue/51#51)</sub></sup>

Comment: But if the 'system' is detecting, how come 2 weeks ago there were lots on multiple sites, but now I can't see a single one on skeptics or fitness?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 There's a decay factor involved.  Perhaps you haven't viewed the tag it inferred for you as much lately?

Comment: Why a decay factor, sounds weird. Is there anywhere we can view these suggested tags. It just seems strange that both those meta posts popped up at the same time I noticed, it must be something that was only implemented recently. Is it possible it's broken? If there is a decay factor, what's the point in it happening only once, shouldn't it recalculate once a week if that's the case. Doesn't seem right that it should happen once and then never again if I don't visit those tags.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593).  It doesn't happen once, that's the point of the decay - so that you don't get locked into a tag if your viewing habits change.