# On tab 'interesting': why most of the questions have yellow bk but couple of them have white?

Tags: support, user-interface

May be it's a feature that I do not understand. It seems that all interesting questions should be yellow or white (because I have already chose the tab).

> [image]

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you. I didn't know. May be ordering confused me (when I saw a white question between yellow ones). Probably they are ordered by votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The yellow background indicates questions that are tagged with your favorite tags.

The white background questions are not.

Comment: OK, why these 2 particular white questions in the list although there are more interesting questions on the SO?

Comment: "Interesting" tab is white because that is just the UI design. Just like how every other tab is white. Interesting questions are ones that have had recent activity, such as an edit or answer posted, and are sorted by most recent. The reason you only have one that isn't yellow is just coincidence. I currently have 5 white questions... just the UI design.

Comment: @sergzach I think the accepted answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93593/what-happened-to-the-interesting-questions) kind of addresses that, but no guarantee that this is how the alogrithm still works

Comment: @sergzach Because SOs algorithm for identifying interesting questions has determined that those questions may be of interest to you, even though they don't have any of your favourite tags on them.