# Recommended questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, unanswered-questions

I would love Stack Overflow to recommend questions for me to answer, based on questions I have answered in the past (perhaps taking into account how many upvotes my answer received).

I find the tagging system too general for finding questions to answer. For example, questions tagged `ravendb` cover a wide range of topics, many of which are out of my comfort zone, but I would probably be inclined to answer a question that is specifically about writing an extension for RavenDB.

I imagine the term vector of a previously answered question could be compared with new questions to yield a set of sensible recommendations.

Just an idea.

Comment: [How the front page currently works](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). (some minor tweaks may have been added since then).

Comment: Thanks Robert. I obviously missed this change. Thought it was still showing questions in strict chronological ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Robert noted in his comment, [this already happens!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) ...But let me explain:

The more you participate on the site, the more information Stack Overflow has on the questions that you're interested in. Sure, you can go to all the effort of defining a list of "interesting" tags - but even if you don't, SO will do it for you - simply visiting questions with the same tag will cause the site to [infer your interest in them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange-ffefc6/72593#72593).

On top of that, asking or answering questions builds a list of tags you're active in in your profile. These are used by the [Unanswered Questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) to determine which questions you might be well-suited to answer.

And *both* of these sets of tags contribute to the aforementioned [customized home page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Now, there's always a chance that the tagging system doesn't adequately reflect your specific interests. Some of this is unavoidable - tags can't be infinitely granular... But in cases where you encounter a poorly-tagged question, take that opportunity to re-tag it, and thereby help the system - and other users - better find questions of interest.

Comment: Garr, I hate the I-know-what-stuff-you-like feature. On Physics.SE it highlights all quantum mechanics questions--annoying since QM is my _most_ O_0 topic. I've disabled it by choosing a nonexistant tag as my favorite :\

Comment: Well, just be thankful it doesn't identify arbitrary phrases in questions as your "favorites" somehow... (Not completely sure, but that *might* have been what Richard was suggesting)

Comment: that would be a nightmare. Not being an expert in anything, I usually give answers on varied topics. I can't even imagine what the system would assume I like :P

Comment: I hadn't seen Jeff's blog post. Thanks for the explanation!